# Exclude StackTrace when serializing Exception to Json using JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json-serialization

I'm using the code below to serialize 'objects' to Json:

```cs
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    };
    var ObjectJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings),
```

However, when I use this same code to serialize an `Exception` object, some properties (like `StackTrace`) are also included:

```json
{
    "StackTrace":"   at SomeFile.cs:line xxx",
    "Message":"Message",
    "Data":{},
    "Source":"Source.Namespace",
    "HResult":-2146233088,
    "MyCustomExceptionProperty":"SomeValue"
}
```

Is there some general way to exclude specific properties (for specific classes, like `Exception`) from being serialized into the Json, without having to apply attributes (like `[JsonIgnore]`) to the original class (like `Exception`), so I can only get this:

```json
{
    "Message":"Message",
    "MyCustomExceptionProperty":"SomeValue"
}
```

It would be nice to have a general solution, but I'm also glad when it will only work for the unwanted `Exception` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create contract resolver - just figure out the filter condition you want:

```
class Resolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        if(typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
            IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
            return props.Where(p => ....... ).ToList();
        }
        return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new Resolver()
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(w, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I added the condition `Where(p => p.PropertyName != "StackTrace")` and now I don't get the StackTrace - For now, this will be OK. Not sure if we want to exclude all other properties, but the idea is clear!